# EditText to Integer

Tags: android, parsing, integer, android-edittext

I want to parse EditText value as integer without using String. Is it possible? Just like:

```
Integer s1=edt1.getText().toInt();
Integer s1=Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText();
```

Comment: No it is not possible you need to use toString() and then parse this to integer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use `toString()` before you can convert to an `Integer`. `getText()` returns and `editable` which - from what I can tell - is not a valid argument for any of the `Integer` conversion methods.

```
int woohoo = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
```

You don't need to create an intermediate string if that's what you're asking. You can just pass the results of methods used to get the input to the `parseInt()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

```
Integer s1 = Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString().trim());
```

But make sure that your edittext input contains only numbers

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be

```
Integer value = Integer.valueOf(edit1.getText().toString())
```